# How do I make an argument a function of the type of another argument?

Tags: haskell, types

I'm writing [Minkowski's question-mark function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_question-mark_function), `?(x)`. The code looks like this:

```
-- Minkowski's question-mark function
import Data.Ratio

mink' :: (Ord a,RealFrac a) => a -> a -> a
mink' toler x
  | toler > 1 = x
  | x == 0 = x
  | x < 0 = (-mink' toler (-x))
  | x >= 1 = (mink' toler (x-1)) +1
  | otherwise = (2 ^^ (-intpart))* (2- mink' (toler/x^2) fracinvx )
  where
    invx=1/x
    intpart=floor invx
    fracinvx=invx-fromIntegral intpart

-- mink :: (Num a,Floating a,RealFrac a) => a -> a
-- mink x = (mink' toler fracx) + intx
--   where
--     intx = fromIntegral (round x)
--     fracx = x-intx
--     (_,ex) = decodeFloat (1::a)
--     toler = 2^^ex

mink :: (Num a,RealFrac a) => a -> a
mink x = (mink' 0 fracx) + intx
  where
    intx = fromIntegral (round x)
    fracx = x-intx
```

`mink x` works as long as `x` is Rational. If I run `mink 0.618034`, however, it hangs. I want to pass one ulp to `toler` if the type of `x` is `Floating`, but pass 0 to `toler` if the type of `x` is `Ratio`. A smaller `toler` works too, as long as it's greater than 0:

```
*Main> mink' 1e-40 (((sqrt 5)-1)/2)
0.6666666666683355
```

(`?(1/φ) == 2/3` exactly, but the function is very steep there.)
How do I make `toler` depend on the type of `x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I make `toler` depend on the type of `x`?

The mechanism for having values depend on types are typeclasses. For example, you could just make `mink` a method:

```
class (Num a, RealFrac a) => Minkowski a where
  mink :: a -> a

instance Minkowski Rational where   -- this will want `-XFlexibleInstances`
  mink x = (mink' 0 fracx) + intx where ...

instance Minkowski Double where
  mink x = (mink' 1e-40 fracx) + intx where ...
```

To have the ε automatically determined from a `decodeFloat`, your approach actually pretty much works. The problem is just that you can't use `a` from a Haskell98-style signature in the function body, this requires `-XScopedTypeVariables`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, UnicodeSyntax #-}

minkFloating :: ∀ a . (Num a,Floating a,RealFrac a) => a -> a
minkFloating x = (mink' toler fracx) + intx
  where
    intx = fromIntegral (round x)
    fracx = x-intx
    (_,ex) = decodeFloat (1::a)
    toler = 2^^ex
```

```
instance Minkowski Double where mink = minkFloating
instance Minkowski Float where mink = minkFloating
```

Comment: So you're making a new typeclass called `Minkowski`? There shouldn't be an instance specifically for `Double`, but for any `Floating`, where `toler` is the type's ulp, which I tried to do in the commented-out code but couldn't get it to work. 1e-40 is overly precise.

Comment: That worked, though I had to add `RealFloat a` to the type signature of `minkFloating`.